# In Spring, How to mapping same table on Entity?

Tags: spring, jpa, report

I want to develop reporting system.

At first, I made [UserReport] table and I put reporter and reportedUser (there are same User type) and I wrote @ManyToOne
but, It doesn't work

Please help me..
Thank you!

I'm not good at English. So I'm sorry for asking question at pooring English

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsDuM.png)

++ I fixed it
The reason is 'explain' is reserved word in MySQL.

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work"? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Server work. but table doesn't exist in MySQL,
-- Error -- 

2022-06-29 22:03:16.838  WARN 11344 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table BoardReport (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        createDate date,
        explain varchar(255) not null,
        reportedBoardId integer not null,
        reporterId integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

Comment: are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Can you please provide the full stacktrace in your question

Comment: Thank! I found what is problem. The reason is 'explain' is reserved word in MySQL. Thank you for recommending for me. :)

Comment: Then please add your own answer. It maybe helpful for others. Thanks